# How to draw a dashed curve joining two points in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to implement the below design. The design should be *supported in all the screen sizes and orientations*. I am not sure how to draw the the highlighted section which adjust in all screens.

[image: template_to_draw]

I have tried following:

- Create a `Row` with `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.Center`.
- Divide `Row` in three section using `Container`.
- The middle `Container` wrapped in is having `Flexible` to take up all available space. Use `borderRadius` to get rounded border.
- Use `Container`'s `transform` property to translate the two container to fall below the ending point of border.

**Result**
[image: rendered_result]

However, the above idea is not working because of following reasons:

- The UI is not rendering as per design. The items z-index are different.
- The center container is having full rounde border.
- The UI is not adjsuting properly in different orientations.

After reading forums and blogs, I guess `CustomPainter` or `ClipPath` should be good candidate for it. Any help is grately appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think `CustomPainter` is the best approach. This post can help you achieve your objectives: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55862786/4800774

To get the starting and ending points, you can use the render box to get global position.

```
GlobalKey nyPointKey = GlobalKey();
Point(key: nyPointKey);
RenderBox box = key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
Offset position = box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
```